# How to add text to video with ffmpeg without vhook?

Tags: ffmpeg

I think question is simple enough. How to add text with ffmpeg vhook is deprecated and i couldn't find any easier solution.

Using ubuntu and installed latest ffmpeg version.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using? You may have to compile ffmpeg because ffmpeg in older Ubuntu repositories does not have filtering capabilities.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard  Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FFmpeg from Ubuntu 10.04 does not appear to support filters, so you will have to get a more recent version. You can follow a step-by-step [guide to compile ffmpeg on Ubuntu](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide), or you can simply download a [Linux build of ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/).

Note that if you follow the compile guide you will need to additionally install `libfreetype6-dev` as a dependency and then add `--enable-libfreetype` to your ffmpeg `./configure`.

This example command will add the words "Stack Overflow" to the video with a white background and centered in the middle of the video:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter:v "drawtext=fontsize=30:box=1:fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Vera.ttf:text='Stack Overflow':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h-line_h)/2" output
```

[image: drawtext example]

See the [`drawtext` documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1) for more details on additional parameters.