# How to make a customized video

Tags: c#, video, video-streaming, video-processing, personalization

I'd like to be able to write some code so that given a name and a video, I can personalize the video with that person's name in it.

Eg, I want to send my family's Christmas message which is a video of us doing silly things and with a video overlay that says Merry Christmas, !

Ideally, I'd like to do this in C#.NET but am open to other technologies if they exist.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ffmpeg utility (https://www.ffmpeg.org) can do this type of thing -  you should be able to find examples if you Google text or video overlays with ffmpeg:

Overlaying images on a video:

- https://video.stackexchange.com/a/12111
- https://superuser.com/a/683696

Overlaying text:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10919953/334402
- https://superuser.com/a/701206 (includes a watermark)

The above are all done on the command line. To include them into your c# program you can:

- invoke the command line from your program
- use a c# wrapper around the ffmpeg command line functionality
- Directly use the libraries that ffmpeg uses

The best compromise may be the wrapper option. These exist for different languages and environments, but some examples for c#:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/774093/Another-FFmpeg-exe-Csharp-Wrapper
- http://www.ffmpeg-csharp.com (this one is not free so check the licence...)